# How to destroy fragment on Back press

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

I have 2 fragments A and B. First opens A fragment, there is button. `onButtonClick` it goes to fragment B. In fragment B the user selects some languages, or something else and `onButtonClick` comes to fragment A. So when it comes to Fragment A and i click back on phone, it goes back again on Fragment B. I want that when the user in Fragment B selects some information, languages and other things and then clicked next button, it destroyed. Something like this. When it goes from A to B, then after selecting information goes from B to A i want to destroy the B fragment. In fragment i can't to override the `onBackPressed` method because this is for activity. Any ideas? Found in internet some samples but they don't helped. If you need the code please say. Thanks for help.

Ok here's the Fragment A.

```
public class PersonalInfoFragment extends BaseFragment {

View mainView;

public static final String TEXT = "TEXT";

TextView dots;
EditText skills_description;
Button clear, save, languages;

CircleImageView circleImageView1, circleImageView2, circleImageView3,
        circleImageView4, circleImageView5, circleImageView6;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_info, container, false);
    init(mainView);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        ArrayList<Integer> s = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("IMAGE");
        if (s != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        circleImageView1.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        circleImageView2.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        circleImageView3.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        circleImageView4.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        circleImageView5.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        circleImageView6.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return mainView;
}


private void init(View v) {
    skills_description = v.findViewById(R.id.skills);
    clear = v.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    languages = v.findViewById(R.id.select_language);
    dots = v.findViewById(R.id.dots);
    save = v.findViewById(R.id.save);

    circleImageView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.language1);
    circleImageView2 = v.findViewById(R.id.language2);
    circleImageView3 = v.findViewById(R.id.language3);
    circleImageView4 = v.findViewById(R.id.language4);
    circleImageView5 = v.findViewById(R.id.language5);
    circleImageView6 = v.findViewById(R.id.language6);

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            skills_description.setText("");
        }
    });

    languages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    new FragmentLanguage()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}}
```

On `languages.setOnClickListener` it goes to Fragment B.

```
languages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    new FragmentLanguage()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

Here's the Fragment B.

```
public class FragmentLanguage extends BaseFragment {

public static final String TEXT = "TEXT";


MyAdapter adapter;

View mainView;
ListView listView;

Button next;

PersonalInfoFragment info = new PersonalInfoFragment();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    listView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    fillData();
    showResult();

    return mainView;
}


public void fillData() {

    ArrayList<Item_obj> objS = new ArrayList<>();

    //Array list of Languages
    objS.add(new Item_obj("Armenian", R.drawable.download, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("Russian", R.drawable.russian, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("US English", R.drawable.usa, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("Portugal", R.drawable.france, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("Spanish", R.drawable.italy, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("Georgian", R.drawable.download, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("French", R.drawable.download, false));
    objS.add(new Item_obj("Italian", R.drawable.download, false));
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), objS);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void showResult() {
    next = mainView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    clear = mainView.findViewById(R.id.clear_lang);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Item_obj> it = adapter.getCheck();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCheck().size(); i++) {
                Item_obj items = it.get(i);
                if (items.isSelected) {
                    list.add(items.image);
                }
            }

            if (list.size() > 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You can't select more than 6 elements", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                list.clear();
            }

            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("IMAGE", list);
            info.setArguments(bundle);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, info).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}}
```

In `next.setOnClickListener` it goes back again to fragment A, with selected languages.

Comment: Can you present your code ?

Comment: Yes of course, wait a minute I'll edit my code.

Comment: I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(yourfragment).commit()
```

add to onBackPressed() or where you set intent from B to A

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new instance of PersonalInfoFragment from FragmentLanguage fragment, instead on pressing of next button you should pass the bundle value to PersonalInfoFragment by creating a callback with interface and call onBackPressed method.

Callback creation code inside FragmentLanguage:

```
private OnNextClickListener mOnNextClickListener;

interface OnNextClickListener{
    void onNextButtonClicked(Bundle bundle);
}

public void setOnNextClickListener(OnNextClickListener 
 mOnNextClickListener) {
    this.mOnNextClickListener = mOnNextClickListener;
}
```

Call mOnNextClickListener.onNextButtonClicked(bundle); when next button pressed and implement the interface in PersonalInfoFragment.